# Python3 argparse: When passing string as arg run funcA, if dashed arg run another func

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

#### Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

When passing a string as the arg, call a write_text() function

`python3 app.py write this text to file`

When passing a dashed arg, call another function, in this case read_text()

`python3 app.py -r`

When passing no args print help

`python3 app.py`

---

#### Here's what I have so far:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('text', help="write text to file")
parser.add_argument('-r', '--read', help="read text from file")
args = parser.parse_args()
...
def main():
  if args.read:
    read_text()
  elif args.text:
    write_text(args.text)
  else:
    parser.print_help()
```

The problem is that when I call just `-r` it complains that it's missing a command for `text`, because `text` is not an optional argument.

I've tried creating subcommands and making all the args subcommands but then the `text` argument needs to be explicitly called like `python3 app.py text`.

I may be thinking too hard on this and overlooking a simple solution. I had this working perfectly just parsing `sys.argv`, but it wasn't pretty. And the built in help function is useful as well.

Thanks in advance!

---

#### Edit:

Here's what I have now that's working

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('text', nargs='*', help="write text to file")
parser.add_argument('-r', '--read', action='store_true', help="read text from file")
args = parser.parse_args()
...
def main():
  if args.read:
    read_text()
  elif args.text:
    text = " ".join(args.text)    
    write_text(text)
  else:
    parser.print_help()
```

Still thinking there may be a cleaner way to do this...

Comment: So, is your problem solved?

Comment: Yep, thanks @cdrom I marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help :

```
parser.add_argument('text', nargs='?', help="write text to file")
```

more info : https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs

---

Note that you should use `action='store_true'` for the *read* argument if you want to use args.read as a boolean later.

```
parser.add_argument('-r', '--read', action='store_true', help="read text from file")
```

Comment: Thank you! `action='store_true'` worked for the `-r` argument. However, after adding `nargs='?'` to the text argument I'm getting an error for unrecognized arguments when passing a string of 4 words to the program.

Comment: When using `nargs='*'` it created a list which I then was able to combine into a string and pass to my function.

Comment: Don't make your script guess as to how you want to join the multiple arguments into a string: be explicit, and do that yourself: `python3 app.py "write this text to file"`.